# JS ES6 Class ToString() Method is not working even with Babel or in Chrome

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

for my below code I want to setup a default toString() method which overrides the inbuilt toString() for this class. But its not working and I get the output "Queue { data: [] }" instead of expected "Hello This is example". I looked at some already discussed similar questions on SO but no help. I also tried on latest version of Chrome and behaviour is same. I have Node 10.13 with Babel 6 (babel-node --presets env,stage-2 queue.js). Looking for some expert opinion here.

```
class Queue {
  constructor() {
    this.data = [];
  }
  toString() {
    console.log("Hello This is example");
  }
}

const queue1 = new Queue();
console.log(queue1);
```

Comment: Thanks Andreas, let str = queue1 + ""; did the trick. I really wonder why console.log() doesnt call it. Now every time I have to console log it, I have to create str before it.

Comment: Because a string is more or less useless (imho) when inspecting (logging) an object.

Answer (score 5):

You have to trigger the call for `.toString()` explicitly or implicitly

```
console.log(queue1.toString());
console.log(queue1 + "");
console.log([queue1, queue2].join());
```

And `.toString()` has to return the string representation:

```
toString() { return "..." }
```

```js
class Queue {
  constructor() {
    this.data = [];
  }
  toString() {
    return "Hello This is example"; // toString has to return the string representation
  }
}

const queue1 = new Queue();
console.log(queue1 + "");

const queue2 = new Queue();
console.log([queue1, queue2].join());
```

Comment: Using template literals is another way to call toString implicitly. So ```console.log(`${queue1}`)``` should give you what you want too.

Comment: @DhruvPrakash There are multiple ways of triggering a call for `.toString()`. Those are only meant as an example and not a complete list of all possibilites.

Answer (score 4):

> for my below code I want to setup a default toString() method which
>   overrides the inbuilt toString() for this class. But its not working
>   and I get the output "Queue { data: [] }" instead of expected "Hello
>   This is example".

```
class Queue {
  constructor() {
    this.data = [];
  }
  toString() {
    console.log("Hello This is example");
  }
}

const queue1 = new Queue();
console.log(queue1);
```

In the above code the `toString` method doesn't override the class's `toString` method. Why? Because the class's `toString` *returns* a String.

In your code, `console.log("Hello This is example");` *doesn't return any value*. That is the reason you are getting the output: *Queue { data: [] }*. This is the default output. If you remove the `toString` method from your `Queue` class, the statement `console.log(queue1);` will still print: *Queue { data: [] }*.

To make the `Queue` class object's representation as a string value, you need to code something like this:

```
toString() {
    return "Hello this is an example";
}
```

To use the `toString` in your application you can try the code on any of the lines #2 or #3 below, and it will print: "Hello this is an example".

```
const queue1 = new Queue();
console.log(queue1); // #2
console.log(queue1.toString()); // #3
```

Also see this [link](http://es6-features.org/#BaseClassAccess) and 
[Object.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString).

Comment: `console.log(queue1); // #2` works only in some environments

Comment: Tnks for inputs, ToString() still doesnt works even after I return a string from ToString() method, But the above answers by andreas and dhruvPrakash works perfectly.  I used queue1 + "" in console.log()

Comment: Then what @Bergi says must be true (_"#2 works only in some environments"_). The code works fine for me so I posted the answer as I saw it. Thanks for the comments.