# Printing out javascript objects

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, tostring

In the example below I have two console.log's, and I'm getting different answers each time (despite my expecting to get the same answer).

```js
class Dog {
  constructor(name, gender) {
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
  }
  toString() {
    return this.name;
  }
}

let maxi = new Dog('john', 'male');
console.log(maxi) // Dog { name: 'john', gender: 'male' }
console.log(`${maxi}`); // john
```

In the first example, it seems like I'm logging the object's type and its properties. In the second example, however, it seems like my custom `toString()` method is being used to convert the object into a string.

Why the difference? And is there a place in the documentation that explains why string literals use the toString() method to convert objects into a string whereas console.log() doesn't. In addition, where does console.log() even pull this string representation of the object?

Thanks!

Comment: `console.log(maxi)` doesn't log the string representation of object. The representation of the object and the prototype chain depends on the browser. But, it logs the reference to the object. If the object were to be updated, if you expand the earlier logged object in the console, it will show the updated properties.

Comment: `toString` behavior is expected. Whenever the object is forced to be a string, it calls the `toString` method on the object: [MDN: Overriding the default toString method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString#overriding_the_default_tostring_method)

Comment: @adiga and console.log() doesn't force a string? How is console.log printing the reference to the object?

Comment: @bugsyb In which environment, node.js or a browser or something else? As adiga said, in a debugger `console.log` will not print text, but display a live representation of the object you can inspect after the fact.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS ES6 Class ToString() Method is not working even with Babel or in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54006707/js-es6-class-tostring-method-is-not-working-even-with-babel-or-in-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

If you log objects in the last versions of chrome or firefox what you get logged is a reference to the object, and probably not the 'value' at the moment when you call the console.log(). but it's the value of the object at that time.
**Reference : [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log)**

So what does fix this problem, convert your object into a string(your log 2), for example:

```js
class Dog {
    constructor(name, gender) {
      this.name = name;
      this.gender = gender;
    }
    toString() {
      return this.name;
    }
  }
  
  let maxi = new Dog('john', 'male');
  console.log('Dog: ' + maxi) // Dog { name: 'john', gender: 'male' }
  console.log(`${maxi}`); // {"name":"john","gender":"male"}
```

this works because I use the + operator instead of the , operator, so he will stick it into the string instead of making a reference to your object.

**Summary**
A variable does not store the value of the object, but a reference (the address in memory) for the value. So your copies that reference instead of the object.

Answer (score 0):

As I think your requirement is to print object in string form so I have this solution below.

Oh I used arrow function here. you can use normal es5 function.
Thank you.

```
class Dog {
  constructor(name, gender) {
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
  }
  toString() {
    return JSON.stringify(this);
  }
}

let maxi = new Dog('john', 'male');
console.log(`${maxi}`); // {"name":"john","gender":"male"}
```

Comment: `console.log(typeof(maxi))` will not print `Dog { name: 'john', gender: 'male' }`. And there's absolutely no reason to use an arrow function here where a method is much better! (Not an ES5 `function` though)

Comment: @Bergi I agree there is no reason for an arrow function *here*, but please explain why using an instance method declaration is "much better" than assigning an anonymous arrow function to a class property. The latter is actually the recommended way to avoid having to do `this.methodName = this.methodName.bind(this)` in the constructor, e.g. for methods that are used as event listeners.

Comment: @Bergi , Hahaha I know typeof(maxi) will not print the object I just used it for my understanding purpose.
but the thing is that next line is giving the solution . we can use both arrow fn and Es5 fn. 
It is just in my habit to use arrow functions that's why I used it. there is nothing wrong to use it.

Comment: @connexo First, class fields are still experimental syntax, nothing that should be taken for granted. Second, they are less efficient and need more memory, which is absolutely unnecessary when not used as an event listener like `toJSON`. And third, they don't work properly with inheritance. See https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1 for more. They should not become a habit. So in this case, the change is absolutely unwarranted.

Comment: @Bergi That post lists problems with the way class properties are *transpiled*, not with the feature by itself. Transpiling is in the midst of becoming a thing of the past though. Also it keeps surprising me how much methods not being bound to the instance *per se* seems like such an immense obstacle for React developers.

Comment: @connexo the article starts with the transpilation only to explain what actually happens when you use class fields. The problems don't go away with native implementations.

Answer (score -1):

I think that Console.log uses internaly a method toJSON in order to transport an object in to string. So you must write your own toJSON...

```
    class Dog {
      constructor(name, gender) {
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
      }
      toJSON() {
        return this.name;
      }
    }
    let maxi = new Dog('john', 'male');
    console.log(maxi) // Dog { name: 'john', gender: 'male' }
    console.log(`${maxi}`); // john
```

This really don't work... as Bergi tell me and he was right. I tried the code without remove the original: toString() { ... } and adding the toJSON() {...} and '>>>' like this: console.log('>>>'+maxi) and take output //>>>john.  So, i thought that the toJSON() give the //>>>john, but it was the toString(). Thank you Bergi.

Comment: No, it does not use `toJSON`.

Comment: I run the code on node, and output is:
john
john

Comment: I cannot reproduce. When running your code, I get `Dog { name: 'john', gender: 'male' }` and `[object Object]`.

Comment: You are right... i modify it like this: console.log('>>>'+maxi) and output //>>>john

Comment: No. Even that only works with `toString`, not with `toJSON`.

Comment: Bergi can you tell me how can run the code on this page with "Run code snippet" ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do. But that's not use node or the browser devtools console, rather a `console` implementation specific to StackOverflow.